# Libre Office Calc time Function

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I want to make a Excel File (Using Libre Office Calc) that calcuates the working time per day, but I'm struggling to get it right as I'd like to have it.

Example:

```
A1 = type in your Start time. eg: 0800  (!!Note: no colon use at typing )
B1 = type in your End time. eg: 1630  (!! Note: no colon use at typing )
C1 = B1-A1/100 = 8.3  (means 8 hours 30 mins)
```

Now I'd like to "convert" 8.3 (8 h 30 min)... into 8.5 format.
And it should be dynamic, because C1 may could be 8.12 which should be a 8.2
Basically it should take the digit after dot and do /60*100.

I don't want to type colons at A1 and B1.

[Here](http://www.upload.ee/files/3466020/sample.ods.html) you can download the sample.

I hope it's somehwat clear what I'd like to do.

Answer (score -1):

Added: It is easier to convert to time and back. You'll probably need to format the cell as General as it will probably attempt to display as a time by default:

```
=24*(TIME(A2/100,MOD(A2,100),0)-TIME(A1/100,MOD(A1,100),0))
```

This is thanks to a colleague of mine, Hans @ eileenslounge.com

Comment: Nice.. Thank you very much.. works good for me :)

and for those who have German language installation like I had. 
    
=GANZZAHL((B1-A1)/100)+(B1-(A1+GANZZAHL((B1-A1)/100)*100))/60

Comment: I just got back working on the file and I noticed the formula has a bug. It works with a Starttime(A1) from X.00 - X.30 If you use X.45 as example you'll get a wrong result.

Comment: The values shouldn't contain dots, so perhaps you can provide a couple of specific values for A1 and A2 that give incorrect results.

Comment: For example A1=845  A2=1630  =8.411 which is wrong.  The formula works if you have A2=1630 and as A1 a number between 800 to 830